# Ads Network Reporting for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, admob, ads, adwhirl

I'm Curious about how all the ad mechanism works.
Let's say I publish my app using 5 networks (adMob,inMobi, etc...).
Each network gives me a slice of code to incorporate inside my initialization function, so
when the app is downloaded, the report will be sent.

Now, someone downloaded my app using one of these networks, let's say by pressing an adMob banner.
Is there a way for my app to know at startup that it was downloaded using adMob, so I won't call all the other 4 network initialization code? I don't see a point making all these redundant calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if it is an iPhone/iOS app it's always downloaded via iTunes App Store so there is no way to see which banner network is just to download your app.

Comment: So, what do you do ? You just report the download at startup to all Ad networks you work with and expect all but the right one to ignore the call ?

Comment: Guess that that will be the way to go.